# How to sort a version list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a method that list some versions of an application on my computer, the list following has this format and the content are strings:

```
['1.15.1.23', '1.10.1.34', '1.9.2.3', ...]
```

When I call `sorted(mylist)`, the output does not appear to sort some items, I'm getting this:

```
['1.15.1.51', '1.15.1.9', '1.15.2.11', '1.15.2.6']
```

What I'm doing wrong? I expected the output as:

```
['1.15.1.9', '1.15.1.51', '1.15.2.6', '1.15.2.11']
```

Comment: Strings are compared character-by-character, so `'10'` comes before `'2'`.

Comment: It works just fine.

Comment: It does work, you must not have used it correctly. But keep making rude posts instead of trying to actually learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supply a `key` to the `sorted` function:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda v: map(int, v.split('.')))
```

Comment: Did you try `mylist.sort(key=...)`? Because that sorts the list in-place and returns `None`. `sorted` definitely returns the result.